# MSI to show uninstalling of old project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have an Installer project for my application in Visual studio 2010. I was successfully able to make it uninstall the older version of the application before installing the new one by 
1. Setting RemovePreviousVersion to false
2. Setting DetectNewInstaller to true
3. Incrementing the project version
4. Creating new product code

Now when I double click my application for installation, I want the the setup wizard to also show that the currently installed application is getting uninstalled before showing the progress bar for fresh installation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

That might be a typo, but you need RemovePreviousVersions=True for the previous version to be uninstalled, as the actual name implies!

Otherwise, this is just the way VS (and most other tools) behave because Windows Installer's upgrades are like that, embedded in the new install. That progress bar behavior includes the uninstall of the old product, not just the fresh install, and the uninstall occurs *after* the new product has been installed. It's all one transaction.

With another tool you could build your own dialog that says there's an upgrade going on based on the detection of the older product, but generally speaking that's quite rare. Customers typically know what they have installed, and they are well aware that they are about to install an upgrade, that seems to be the assumption behind the default behavior.